# Using Implicit Euler with second order differential equations

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We can numerically integrate first order differential equations using Euler method like this:
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hf(t_n, y_n)$$

And with Implicit Euler like this:
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hf(t_{n+1},y _{n+1})$$

If I have a differential equation $y' - ky = 0$, I can integrate $y$ numerically using Implicit Euler:
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hky_{n+1}$$
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n\frac{1}{1-hk}$$

But how I do use Implicit Euler for second order differential equations, like for instance the equation for simple harmonic motion?
$$y'' + w^2y = 0$$

We have to integrate with respect to $y$ and $y'$. For explicit Euler the numerical integration would look like this (?):
$$y_{n+1}  = y_n + hf(t_n, y'_n)$$
$$y'_{n+1}  = y'_n + hg(t_n, y_n)$$

How would we do integrate using Implicit Euler instead?

Comment: It is almost always a good idea to express higher-order ODEs in their equivalent first-order form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. For convenience, name the derivative $v_n=y_n'$. Then
\begin{align}
y_{n+1}&=y_n+hv_{n+1}\\
v_{n+1}&=v_n-hw^2y_{n+1}\\
\implies
y_{n+1}(1+h^2w^2)&=y_n+hv_n\\
v_{n+1}(1+h^2w^2)&=v_n-hw^2y_n
\end{align}
which looks like an explicit Euler method with a correction factor.